# My image background covers all my outputs

Tags: ios

Im a beginner in programing iOS, so I have 2 questions:

1- I have a `UIViewcontroller` which load a few `uiview` and user is able to move them via touch. Now I want to put an image background in this way:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"board.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

But the image covers over all uivews!!

2- As I said, I move my uiviews by touch and when they have collided in the end touch they both goes in a folder, and a folder is created. So I want to know how I can make that a special image shows on the created folder ??

```
if (view != toMove && CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame,toMove.center)) {

            viewToBefolder = view;
}
```

Comment: You are probably better off splitting this into two separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your background view first, and then the rest of the views you add will be on top, or just do this:

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image view is covering the the background, you should be setting the size and position of the image view, or setting the constraints so that it is added at the size and position that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set your imageview into the main window.

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
        [self.window addSubview:backgroundView];
        [self.window sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

Then set all your view controller view **clear color.** so, By default it's always display background image view into the all view.